# Android - Register/Unregister Receiver Dynamically using a Helper Class with Static Methods?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

**THE SITUATION:**
I have a 'helper' class with static methods, to dynamically enable/disable a BroadcastReceiver.
I call these methods from other classes, when I need to register (or) unregister the Receiver.

**THE ISSUE:**
I can't figure out how to dynamically **UN**Register the receiver from within the helper class..
(When I try to do `context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);` it doesn't recognize `myReceiver`).

**THE QUESTION:**
How do I properly reference `myReceiver` from the `receiverUnregister` method in the Code below?

---

```
public class GpsReceiverHelper {


    //  Called from a different Class when I need to Register the Receiver
    public static void receiverRegister(Context context) {

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");

        final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //  Receiver code goes here    
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }



    //  Called from a different Class when I need to UN-Register the Receiver
    public static void receiverUnregister(Context context) {

        //  THIS DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE "myReceiver" can't be found..
        context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    }


}
```

Again, I plan to call these Methods from within a different class.
**What is the proper way to go about doing this, and properly assign everything?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by adding Field entries for `static BroadcastReceiver myReceiver` and then assigning it like `myReceiver= ...` inside of my static method containing the actual BroadcastReceiver code.. Furthermore, I realized I could avoid the BroadcastReceiver being killed upon calling `finish();` simply by replacing `context.registerReceiver` with `context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver`. Problem(s) solved!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to keep references to all the receivers you register. You can do this in different ways. One way is to have a static collection that holds them in this helper class (not the best approach). Another way is to return the receiver in your `receiverRegister` method. This way whoever is calling the method has to maintain the reference and later on use it to unregister.

```
public BroadcastReceiver registerReceiver(...) {
  ...
  return receiver;
}

public void unregisterReceiver(Context context, BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
  context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Comment: **HOWEVER**, I do still have an issue.. After I make the call to register the receiver, as soon as I call `finish();` to close the activity window (so the BroadcastReceiver can remain running in the background), it kills the BroadcastReceiver immediately upon calling `finish();`.. How can I avoid this, while still closing the current activity window?

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the process by making `intentFilter` as member of `GpsReceiverHelper` class and basically removing the `static` keyword from `recieverRegister` and `receiverUnregister`.

```
public class GpsReceiverHelper {

    private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //  Receiver code goes here    
            }
    };

    //  Called from a different Class when I need to Register the Receiver
    public void receiverRegister(Context context) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    //  Called from a different Class when I need to UN-Register the Receiver
    public void receiverUnregister(Context context) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

The code above is now a real Helper class rather than just a utility class with a bunch of static methods.

Example usage:

```
class TestActivity extends Activity{
  private GpsRecieverHelper helper = new GpsRecieverHelper();

  public void onStart(){
      helper.receiverRegister(this);
  }

  public void onStop(){
      helper.receiverUnregister(this);
  }
}
```

If you need to reuse the same instance of the helper you can use public static keyword:

`public static GpsRecieverHelper helper = new GpsRecieverHelper();`

The helper above is now accessible in every class e.g. `<NameOfTheCLass>.helper`.

Disclaimer : I never tested the code myself in an actual IDE.